# How do I use hover to move to an anchor?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if I am able to achieve this using only CSS and HTML or if I need to use Javascript since after researching for a while I didn't really find much information on how to do this.

I haven't tried anything since I'm not really sure how I would go about this.

CSS:

```css
        * {
     font-family: Montserrat;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    .menu {
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px;
     background-color: white;
     padding-top: 1%;
     box-shadow: 10px -120px 900px 117px rgba(0,89,255,1);
    }
    
    ul {
     color: black;
     list-style: none;
     margin-top: 1%;
     font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    li {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline;
     margin-left: 5%;
     border-radius: 55px;
     border-color: #005cff;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     padding: 0.2% 3% 0.2% 3%;
     background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #62EF62 50%, white 50%);
        -webkit-transition: background-position 2s;
        -moz-transition: background-position 2s;
        transition: 2s;
    }
    
    .first-title:hover {
     padding: 0.2% 6% 0.2% 6%;
     color: #005cff;
     font-size: 25px;
     background-position: 444.7 0%;
    
    }
    
    .second-title:hover {
     padding: 0.2% 6% 0.2% 6%;
     color: #005cff;
     font-size: 25px;
     background-position: 303 0%;
    
    }
    
    .third-title:hover {
     padding: 0.2% 6% 0.2% 6%;
     color: #005cff;
     font-size: 25px;
     background-position: 332 0%;
    
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%
    }
    
    .logo {
     float: left;
     margin-top: 1%;
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 64px;
     transition: 2s;
    }
    
    .logo:hover {
     width: 260px;
     height: 83px;
     margin-top: 0.5%;
     margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header class="sticky">
     <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
     <div class="menu">
      <ul>
       <li class="first-title">O que é o Artigo 19?</li>
       <li class="second-title">Portfólio</li>
       <li class="third-title">Entrevistas</li>
      </ul>
     <div>
     </header>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to when hovering over a list element, for it to go down to an anchor point.

Comment: please show more of your code

Comment: Is your intention to scroll to an anchor point on hover of the anchor link?

Comment: Can you show your HTML too?

Comment: please create a code snippet of working code. thanks

Comment: just updated the code

Comment: yes @guitarzero that is my goal

Comment: Imho, I think you absolutely should use javascript. That would be such a bad experience if someone accidentally hovered over something and they were moved to an anchor point on the page. You should add a delay to make sure the user actually means to hover.

Comment: Well this is for a school project and our group's idea was for our website to be clickless, and yes the delay I was thinkling of putting was of around 2 seconds (while the green bar loads)

Comment: I'd strongly object against doing those type of actions on hover. The user doesn't expect anything in that direction. That makes scrolling on hover a terrible UX

Comment: you surely have to use javascript for doing the same on hover and if you want scrolling it will be implemented using click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most compatible way you can do this is to have links to anchors on which you simulate a click "on hover" some other elements.

By example:

```
<div id="somewhere">...</div>
...
<a id="gotoSomewhere" href="#somewhere">...</a>
...
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('gotoSomewhere').click();">...</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pgtozf25/